# Using a pattern as a dictionary key

Tags: python, dictionary, pattern-matching, backslash

I'm trying to perform a set of search and replace in a file at once. For that, I'm using a dictionary where the pattern to search is the key, and the replacement text is the key value. I compile all the substitutions in a single pattern and I do the search-replace using the code below:

```
re_compiled = re.compile("|".join(k for k in sub_dict))

# Pattern replacement inner function
def replacement_function(match_object):
    key = str(match_object.group(0))
    if key.startswith(r'C:\work\l10n'):
        key = key.replace("\\", "\\\\")
        key = key[:-1] + '.'
    return sub_dict[key]

while 1:
    lines = in_f.readlines(100000)
    if not lines:
        break
    for line in lines:
        line = re_compiled.sub(replacement_function, line)
        out_f.write(line)
```

I define the dictionary as follows:

```
g_sub_dict = {
                r'C:\\work\\l10n\\.' : r'/ae/l10n/'
              , r'maxwidth="0"'      : r'maxwidth="-1"'
              , r'></target>'        : r'>#####</target>'
             }
```

I've had a bit of a headache with the first key (which is a Windows path, and uses backslashes) mainly because it is used as a pattern.

- Dictionary definition: `r'C:\\work\\l10n\\.'` I escape the backslashes because that string is going to be used as a pattern.
- If I print the dictionary: `C:\\\\work\\\\l10n\\\\.` Backslashes appear double escaped, I understand because I'm defining the string as raw.
- If I walk the dictionary and print the keys: `C:\\work\\l10n\\.` I see exactly what I wrote as raw string. It is a bit confusing that printing the whole dictionary reports a different string than printing a single key, but I guess that has to do with "print dictionary" implementation.
- What I read from file: `'C:\work\l10n\.'` Non escaped backslashes.
- What I have to do to use what I read from file as a dictionary key: escape the backslashes, and transform the text to `C:\\work\\l10n\\.`

Could this code be simplified somehow? E.g. so that I wouldn't need to escape backslashes by code?

Comment: Maybe you can try to use the base64 encrypted string of the file-location? Should be a key easier to handle...

Comment: Thanks @Alex, that can be a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
>>> text = r'start C:\work\l10n\. normal data maxwidth="0" something something ></target> end'
>>> # sub_dict format: {'symbolic_group_name': ['pattern', 'replacement']}
...
>>> sub_dict = {'win_path': [r'C:\\work\\l10n\\.', r'/ae/l10n//'],
...             'max_width': [r'maxwidth="0"', r'maxwidth="-1"'],
...             'target': [r'></target>', r'>#####</target>']}
>>> p = re.compile("|".join('(?P<{}>{})'.format(k, v[0]) for k, v in sub_dict.items()))
>>> def replacement_function(match_object):
...   for group_name, match_value in match_object.groupdict().items():
...     if match_value:
...       # based on how the pattern is compiled 1 group will be a match
...       # when we find it, we return the replacement text
...       return sub_dict[group_name][1]
...
>>> new_text = p.sub(replacement_function, text)
>>> print(new_text)
start /ae/l10n// normal data maxwidth="-1" something something >#####</target> end
>>>
```

Using named groups allows you to rely on a simple string for lookup in your replacement dictionary and won't require special handling for `\`.

EDIT:

About the change in regex pattern: I changed your a|b|c pattern to use named groups. A named capture group has the syntax `(?P<name>pattern)`. Functionally it is the same as having `pattern`, but having a named group allow to obtain data from the `Matcher` object using the group name (e.g.: `matcher.group('name')` vs `matcher.group(0)`)

The `groupdict` method returns the named groups from the pattern and the value they matched. Because the pattern is `group1|group2|group3` only 1 group will actually have a match; the other 2 will have a `None` value in the dict returned by `groupdict` (in my words from the example: `match_value` will be != None only for the group that caused the match).

The benefit is that the group name can be any plain string (preferably something simple and related to the purpose of the pattern) and it will not cause issues with `\` escaping.

Comment: Greate @flavius_st. Just as a note, I've edited my question to remove an extra '/' that I noticed in `/ae/l10n//'. But that is completely unimportant. Now back to your solution, it looks interesting to me. Could you explain a bit more the "compile" line (especially the pattern `(?P<{}>{})'`? Many thanks.

Comment: @flavius_st Thanks. Closing this question as I haven't received more answers in quite some time, and this answer seems quite fair to me.